# Installing PostGIS in Ubuntu

Tags: postgis, installation, pgrouting, ubuntu, linux

I will be installing PostGIS for my project using PostgreSQl (OSM) in Ubuntu 9.04. I had all the requirements prior to the installation (PostgreSQL, Proj4, GEOS). When I unzip the PostGIS tar, then './configure' it, it says that the pg_config.h file is missing. I found out that I need to 'apt-get install libpq-dev' for me to able to have this file and past it as parameter to ./configure --with-pgconfig=PATH. When I executed this, this is what happens:

```
...
checking for libiconv_open in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open in -lc... yes
Using user-specified pg_config file: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h
./configure: line 16394: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16404: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16405: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16406: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
checking PostgreSQL version...
./configure: line 16411: test: : integer expression expected
./configure: line 16416: test: : integer expression expected
./configure: line 16426: test: : integer expression expected
./configure: line 16433: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16434: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16439: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16440: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16445: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
./configure: line 16449: /usr/include/postgresql/pg_config.h: Permission denied
checking libpq-fe.h usability... no
checking libpq-fe.h presence... no
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
configure: error: could not find libpq-fe.h
```

I checked in the /usr/include/postgresql/ directory and I found the pg_config.h and libpq-fe.h files there.

What can I be missing here?

Comment: Are you running ./configure as the root user?

Comment: yes, I am. I logged in as root to make sure.

Comment: I suspect that `'apt-get install libpq-dev` didn't work properly, as the 9.04 distro is no longer supported (too old). Can you run the `pg_config` command?

Comment: @Mike I only now saw your comment, but posted a similar answer -- have to make sure the Postgres install went cleanly, which should be OK but is potentially tricky on an unsupported system.

Comment: I am having the same problem .

Answer (score 2):

You may need to elevate your permission level for the install to work. ( I believe `sudo !!` will re-do the previous command with elevated permissions.)

Otherwise, perhaps `pg_config.h` is currently marked as read-only.

Comment: I'm logged in as root

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the package available on Synaptic:

[image]

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 9.04. I cannot see that in my Synaptic. Does my Ubuntu version matters here?

Comment: if it does not appear, try to activate the 'universe' packages.

Comment: You might want to update your OS, since Ubuntu 9.04 "Jaunty Jackalope" was dropped from support 23 Oct 2010

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what method you used to install the Postgresql portion, because if I remember correctly, it installs the DBMS through a 'new user' called 'postgres'.

Have you tried to run the PostGIS configure through the postgres user? I believe that user has write permissions to those files your user is being denied.

try from the command line: `sudo -u postgres ./configure`

It should ask for your su password.

The easiest way by far to install postgis into your postgresql db is to use the '[Stack Builder](http://stackbuilder.projects.postgresql.org/)' that comes with postgresql.

You can also configure the permissions to allow other users to have write access.
That exact process I can't remember but it is in the Postgresql documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the PostGIS installer at the location of the `pg_config` binary, by adding the `--with-pg` variable pointing at wherever the `pg_config` binary is installed on your machine. `pg_config`, something like:

```
--with-pg=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config
```

You can locate its specific location on your machine with `which pg_config`.

Answer (score 0):

With PostGIS 2.0.3 and Postgresql 9.2.3 installed from source on Ubuntu 12.10, I found this to work:

```
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config
```

Previously, I'd tried to be clever by linking some pgsql binaries and includes but that didn't work. Best to stick the prescribed method.